# Link a programmatic instantiation of class x in class y to a view controller of class x

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have classes `Compose` and `Haiku`, each connected to a view controller in IB.  `Haiku` is instantiated in `Compose` as `ghhaiku`.  `Haiku` has an array, `self.arrayOfHaiku`, with 117 members.  But in `Compose`, `self.ghhaiku.arrayOfHaiku` has no members.

I think the problem is that I haven't linked the instance of `Haiku` that has the 117-member array with the instance of `Haiku` created in `Compose`.  But how do I do that?

(I could of course be totally wrong and the problem could be something else, but that seems to make intuitive sense.)

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**

`Haiku.m` contains the following code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

    [self.arrayOfHaiku addObjectsFromArray:userH];

    NSLog(@"%d",self.arrayOfHaiku.count); //This logs 117.

    [self goToNextHaiku];
}
```

`Compose.h` contains the line `@property (strong, nonatomic) Haiku *ghhaiku;`

`Compose.m` contains the following code:

```
@synthesize ghhaiku;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Lots of other code
    NSLog(@"%d",self.ghhaiku.arrayOfHaiku.count); //this logs 0.
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code? We will need to see how you're instantiating these

Comment: How are you pushing Compose screen from Haiku? Can you please post that code also?

Comment: bad haiku Coda // seven five seven needed // you have too many

Comment: just to clarify Compose and Haiku are separate `ViewControllers`?

Comment: Instances don't share // two classes share one object // arrays are not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you are never initializing the ghaiku, just defining it. Also why is haiku have a viewDidLoad method? Basically you need to do something like:

```
 self.ghhaiku = [[Haiku alloc] initWithData:SOME_ARRAY];
```

in your Compose.m

Just an fyi, if `Haiku` is just a model class you shouldn't use it as a view/viewcontroller. Just as an NSObject. Then just do:

```
-(id)initWithData:(NSArray*)data{
self = [super init];
if(self){
    self.arrayOfHaiku = data;
}
return self;
}
```

just remember to define the method in your `Haiku.h`

```
-(id)initWithData:(NSArray*)data;
```

---

**READ THIS FIRST**
Ok I originally misunderstood what you were doing but I think you should still make a `Haikus` singleton class (i will update the above code to reflect that later when I have more time -- or you can google) then just call `[Haikus sharedInstance].arrayOfHaikus`in each of your view controllers.

Comment: Thanks so very much for the care you took answering this.  It turned out to be about initializing--I had initialized an instance of the Haiku class in a THIRD class, not included in the question, which is always called before Compose.  I was just assuming that the initialization stuck around--i.e., that if I initialized self.ghhaiku in ThirdClass, then self.ghhaiku would be initialized and available to Compose as well.  But then I lazily instantiated it in Compose, and lo and behold! it hadn't existed--so I added initialization to the lazy instantiation in Compose.  Problem solved.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working, but try to keep your pattern MVC. You won't regret doing it.

Comment: That's my next step--working on moving things around so that it's MVC now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this....

```
    //haiku.h

    //haiku.m
    -(NSArray *)initHaikuMembers
    {
        return([[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects.....]);
    }


    //compose.h

    //compose.m
    haiku *ghaiku = [[haiku alloc] init];
    NSArray *myHaikuArray = [ghaiku initHaikuMembers];
```

This way you can instantiate a Haiku class multiple times within Compose and init them at-will if needed. If you need to manipulate the data within myHaikuArray you can allow the Haiku class to do all of the work.